# My selenium web scraper doesn't make sense to me

Tags: selenium, tkinter, web-scraping

I want to get the bitcoin price using the following code. I have no clue why the output behaves that way. It appears to store certain values and outputs them in-between accurate values. Bonus task: Make the old values disappear in tkinter [image: Screenshot from Output]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Downloading pertinent Python packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import tkinter as tk
import time

time = 1000



def bitcoinTracker():
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
    chromedriver = "/Users/Philipp/PhytonWebScrap/selenium_project/chromedriver" #Setting up Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
    driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/")
    hunt = driver.find_element_by_class_name("priceValue___11gHJ").text
    return(hunt)
    driver.quit()
    
def collector():
    label = tk.Label(text="Bitcoin " + bitcoinTracker(), font="Arial 18")
    label.pack()
    root.after(time, collector)
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.after(time, collector)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to narrow the problem down a bit more. Can you share what you've done to try to debug this? Do you know if the problem is with displaying the values, or if it's in getting the values?

Comment: the collector function calls the function bitcoinTracker, which then opens a chrome setting and gets the value of bitcoin from the url, called "hunt". Hunt gets then passed on to the tkinter label. My output irritates me a lot, since the numbers are sometimes out of range of what was displayed on coinmarketcap. That means I get an ouput that was greater than any bitcoin value in "recent" time by a greater margin. So the numbers must come from earlier on which I simply don't understand

Comment: So, the problem is with getting the values, not displaying the values? It would probably be a good idea to take tkinter out of the equation and create a [mcve] that only gets the values. That will help you with debugging the issue.

Comment: I can run the same code the way you suggest but that doesnt fix anything, the numbers are then just printed somewhere else

Comment: Right, but the point is to create a _minimal_ example that has as few lines of code as possible to reproduce the problem. You may have two problems here, but a question needs to focus on one. And since it's impossible to display the value correctly in tkinter if the value itself is wrong, you first need to solve the problem of getting wrong values. Once your code is returning the correct values, we can focus on the second part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I try again this time only selenium without tkinter

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Downloading pertinent Python packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

while True:
    chromedriver = "/Users/Philipp/PhytonWebScrap/selenium_project/chromedriver" #Setting up Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
    driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/")
    hunt = driver.find_element_by_class_name("priceValue___11gHJ").text
    #print(driver.page_source)
    time.sleep(20)
    print(hunt)
driver.quit()
```